Auto Key presser for a specific window
the script seems to be not working
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

running := 0

F3::
{
    global running
    if (running = 0) {
        running := 1
        SetTimer(SpamKey, 50)  ; Increased delay to 50ms to ensure game registers keypresses
        ToolTip("F Spam: ON")
    } else {
        running := 0
        SetTimer(SpamKey, 0)
        ToolTip("F Spam: OFF")
        SetTimer(() => ToolTip(), -1000)
    }
}

SpamKey()
{
    if WinActive("ahk_exe GenshinImpact.exe") {
        SendInput("{F down}")
        Sleep(30)
        SendInput("{F up}")
    }
}

; Emergency stop hotkey
F4::
{
    global running
    running := 0
    SetTimer(SpamKey, 0)
    ToolTip("F Spam: STOPPED")
    SetTimer(() => ToolTip(), -1000)
}

I tried this script where i needed the F key to be spammed continuously until I hit the f3 hotkey to stop it and the specific window being Genshin Impact but its not working and shows something like this
--- C:\Users\X\Documents\AutoHotkey\Genshin.ahk
002: isActive := 0
005: targetWindow := "Genshin Impact"
008: {
022: {
028: Exit (138.70)
Press [F5] to refresh.


